# GRASS plugin absent from QGIS 2.6 OSGeo4W install

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, plugins

I've just installed QGIS 2.6 Brighton using the OSGeo4W installation. The GRASS toolbox plugin has not, however installed as it had been with previous versions. Before, I was able to access the GRASS Tools via the tab Vector > GRASS, but it is now absent. Is this a change in the software or due to an error in the installation? If so, how can I rectify this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-run the setup, change to `advanced install` and look if the package `grass` is selected. It should be selected automatically as dependency.

If it is, look under `Processing -> Options -> Dataproviders -> GRASS commands`. The first item should be checked.

Finally, make sure to switch to `advanced interface` at the bottom of the processing toolbox. You should see 168 geoalgorithms available for GRASS.

BTW, GRASS has been part of Sextante/Processing for quite some time now (at least since QGIS 1.8).

Comment: I've used the grass Tools from the processing toolbox, but sometimes have reverted to the separate GRASS toolbox as the algorithms work differently (sometimes better). I do see the GRASS algorithms when checking the Advanced interface in the processing toolbox. Has the other toolbox been discontinued?

Comment: GRASS has been moved into the QGIS Sextante toolbox way back in 2012. You may still use the standalone application.